# tkinter - How to not process further code if error is not fixed - messagebox.showerror()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter app where I have Labels, Entries and Button. Whenever I click the button, the entries get passed to a function where they are verified according to a format.

For example -

Two fields - Employee Name, Employee Id

Now, I wish to check if username starts with "EMP" or not. For that I have made some functions(like checks if alphanumeric or not etc). If the username does not start with "EMP", what I am doing now is showing an error box like this

```
def tracking_images(self,emp_id,emp_name):
    emp_id, emp_name = emp_id.get(), emp_name.get()
    if len(emp_id) == 0:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Field error", "Employee ID cannot be empty")
    elif len(emp_name) == 0:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Field error", "Employee name cannot be empty")
    
    if not ValidationConditions().first_three_chars(emp_id):
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Field error", "Employee ID should start with EMP")
    ........
    ........
    #Some more code which I don't want user to have until he/she fixes the error from above checks.  <-------
```

Now, after the user clicks "Ok" to any prompt, The code which I don't want user to access still accesses.

How to not user process further until he fixes the errors from the above checks ?

Comment: The simple way is to add `return` after every `tk.messagebox.showerror(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 But if I am not mistaken, it would take me back to the function who called my "tracking_images" function, right ? and then I will have to add more checks over there, like, if the tracking_image has been called before or not, right ?

Comment: As I don't have the full picture of your design, I just provide comment on the question based on the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this in a `do-while` manner (even if pyhton does not support this semantically)

Pseudo code would look like this:

```
while True:
    ask the name
    if the name passes the checks break out of the loop
    show errors

code to go to when the name is valid
```

EDIT: I forgot to note that, as mentioned below, this would have to be done in an extra thread.

Another thing that might work is putting the dialogs in a method that calls itself if the name is invalid to start over.

But I never tried that and cannot test it since I am commuting right now.

Comment: while loop will freeze tkinter application if you don't take some measures.Are you sure that?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right, I forgot to mention that this should be on another thread or done recursively

Comment: I made some changes similar to what you suggested(with of course some checks so that messagebox does not get stuck in a loop). It worked. Thanks.